# How to grab m3u8 from Network-Stream (Python)

Tags: python, stream, traffic, m3u8, sniffing

so currently I'm trying to grab the m3u8 master from the following website:

> https://www.southpark.de/alle-episoden/s22e09-unfulfilled#source=06a1ddfa-d278-45ad-a5ea-2667a3c33752:896b2aa3-ac17-11e8-b956-70df2f866ace&position=9&sort=!airdate

If I open the developer tools in Chrome and look at the network traffic I'm able to grab the m3u8 master url/file and download it.

[SCREENSHOT](https://upld.im/images/Zbb8o.png)

How can I recieve this url/file in python?

This is an example of the direct-url of the m3u8 "sniffed" of the network-stream:

> https://dlvrsvc.mtvnservices.com/api/gen/gsp.comedystor/com/sp/season-22/2209/acts/5/,stream_1280x720_3242151_1491838638/master.m3u8?account=southparkstudios.com&cdn=level3&tk=st=1567425339~exp=1567511739~acl=/api/gen/gsp.comedystor/com/sp/season-22/2209/acts/5/*~hmac=246a92f19e31b7e45ff138d1e7fa8e5cd3be9dc0e265adbac617e179bab411f3

Downloading the m3u8 with python is no problem as long as I get the above shown direkt link to it. 
I don't know how to extract the m3u8-url from the page as it's not in the source code but only appearing in the network stream/tab in the dev tools. It seems like I have to sniff the traffic?
Do you have any idea how to do this?

*Please don't recomment youtube-dl for doing this task as I want to try this by myself. Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use selenium to intercept xhr response using post i thing